# using 2 different app together with appium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, appium

I'm trying to use 2 different apps with appium. it should work like open the first app and do some task send app to background then open second app app do some task and launch first app from background then continue to do first task. I'm using android 10 with real device and latest version of appium. I'm writing this in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two driver with two different app and you can manage both driver as per your need.
Check [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/two-apps-in-a-single-script/15080/9)

Comment: this is not a solution I wanna continue where I left in the first app. But this way apps starting from 0.

Comment: 1) you can minimise your 1st app in background with driver.runAppInBackground
2) then launch second app and perform action 
3) launch 1st app from background

check here : https://discuss.appium.io/t/switching-between-two-apps/22843